# How convert SQL Server 2008 R2 database to SQL Server 2012 completely

Tags: sql, sql-server

How open my SQLServer2008R2 database in SQLServer2012. When I open the database these problems happened:

I can't edit and open tables because this error show:

> Invalid prefix and suffix characters.

When I want design tables this error show:

> The backend version isn't supported to design database diagram or tables.

Comment: how exact did you open it in sql server 2012 ? Did you made a backup and imported the backup ? Did you shut down the 2008 and attached the DB files to the 2012 ? Or some other method ?

Comment: Hi, I deattached database from  SQL Server 2008 and open database in SQL server 2012.

Comment: You should back it up then restore it.

Comment: Hi, I back database up and restore in SQL Server 2012, but those problems shown again.

Comment: "edit and open tables" is a client tool function. What client tool are you using? I guess it's SSMS? Try upgrading to a newer version.

Comment: Hi Nick.McDermaid, Very thanks. My problem solved.

Comment: Hi Nick.McDermaid, Many thanks, I updated SSMS to 2012 and my problem was solved.

Answer (score 3):

When you detach and attach database, the compatibility level of old database is maintained. It is one of the limitations of detach and attach method.
[Reference](https://www.sqlshack.com/move-a-sql-database-using-the-detach-and-attach-method/)

> If we attach a database having a higher version, SQL Server maintains
> the database compatibility. We can change the compatibility level once
> the database is online

Once you change the compatibility level to suit SQL Server 2012, you can use the new features of the SQL Server 2012.

[Read more on upgrading database](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1436/upgrading-sql-server-databases-and-changing-compatibility-levels/)

```sql
ALTER DATABASE DatabaseName SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 110
GO
```